# is there any way to force the use of clang-11 on wllvm

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to use [wllvm](https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm) to extract the bitcode of an executable and get the dotfiles of each function out of the bitcode.
But I am trying to use devirtualization (making function call to a function ptr explicitly state which function it could call, in particular), and to do that I need to use clang-11,
(the software I am going to use: https://github.com/SRI-CSL/clam-prov) but when you do

`sudo apt-get install clang`

now it installs clang-10 instead of clang-11 Ubuntu20.04.

In short, I want to force wllvm to use clang-11 instead so that it will be consistently using the same version, does anyone know how?
I have llvm-11 and clang-11 installed already.

Comment: try setting the `LLVM_COMPILER` environment variable: https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm/blob/7d1380692a0476daa766f21ea5664d04006cf98d/wllvm/compilers.py#L264 https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm/blob/584a3e1650679946ee102ac6f45b61251ff0cf99/README.md#usage

Answer (score 1):

```
export LLVM_COMPILER=clang
export LLVM_CC_NAM=clang-11
export LLVM_CXX_NAME=clang++-11
```